# Meaning of Path expression

Tags: java, rest, jersey

Can you tell how does the following path expression resolve?. I am having it on top of a REST api.

@Path("{a:forgotpwd|forgot/pwd/apitoken}")

Where Path is `javax.ws.rs.Path`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/6nmq2cp26/index.html

`a` is the name of a path parameter, and `forgotpwd|forgot/pwd/apitoken` is the regex its value must match.

So:

```
@Path("{a:forgotpwd|forgot/pwd/apitoken}")
@GET
Response foo(@PathParam("a") a) {
  if (a.equals("forgotpwd") {
     ...
  } else {
     ...
  }
}
```

will match the URLs `forgotpwd` or `forgot/pwd/apitoken` (with whatever leading component is configured of course). Other paths will return 404.